# Scala Spray Routing Syntax

Tags: scala, spray

Here's the code from an example:

```
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp

object Main extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {

      implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")

      startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
             path("hello") {
                  get {
                    complete {
                        <h1>Say hello to spray</h1>
                    }
                 }
             }
       }
}
```

Found at http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/#spray-routing

Please forgive my noobiness, as I come from a Java background... I'm trying to pick up the Scala language as well this framework at the same time. I semantically understand what's happening here, but syntactically I'm very confused.

I'd like to understand what constructs in the Scala language are applied here, specifcally starting from the call to "startServer" and the implementation in between the {}. That way I can Google it up and research it...but I'm not sure what to look up here. I think it may be related some of the functional concepts in the language.

"startServer" seems to be a method of the SimpleRoutingApp, but it looks like you are passing in nested functions into its body, i.e "path", "get", "complete" ...How does this exactly work? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spray is not the easiest thing to learn, especially when you just started with Scala, but i'll try to explain.

The first thing you need to understand is [currying](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-currying-scala). In two words curried function is a function which returns another function. So `startServer` is a good example of a curried function, here it's shortened signature:

```
def startServer(interface: String, port: Int)(route: ⇒ Route): Future[Http.Bound]
```

This is one way to declare a curried function, startServer takes a host and a port, then "return" a function which takes your service `route` and returns a future with `Http.Bound`. Next trick which is allowed in Scala, is that you can write **one arg list** in curly braces like `{}`, and this is used in `startServer`, the first arg list contains two required parameters, so you can't use `{}` style, only `()`, but when you pass `host:port`, you have a function `Route => Future[Http.Bound]`, so you can apply this style. And this rule can be applied further (with `path`, `get`, `complete`).

What you have inside, i.e

```
path("hello") {
    get {
      complete {
          <h1>Say hello to spray</h1>
      }
   }
}
```

is your actual service [Route](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/key-concepts/routes/). It consists of so called [directives](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/key-concepts/directives/), which are based on shapeless implementation of HList (i won't explain it here, but you can find info out there). In general each directive is a function which does something with user HttpRequest (basically RequestContext). Description for all directives can be found [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/predefined-directives-alphabetically/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can you point me to some documentation on that syntactic sugar in which a one arg list method can be applied with {} instead of ()? Thanks!

Comment: @acspd7 [from Scala book](http://books.google.ru/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=Scala+one+arg+list+curly+braces&source=bl&ots=FMli-HHKvu&sig=-tX8a0dLvpaRxp_CSX6D4y11KvY&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=NZi9U6iVCsG8ygOPtoLQBA&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Scala%20one%20arg%20list%20curly%20braces&f=false)